# why my Nodejs / NestJs promise is returning undefined to variable in second function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, nestjs

I have 2 functions. when I called 1st function promise from second function it prints the output correct but my 'newdata' variable in second function is returning undefined value. Please help.

My functions are:

```
async keycloaktokennew(data: any):Promise<any>
  {      
     return  await this.httpService.axiosRef.post(
      `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`,
      querystring.stringify({
        username: 'stdev', //gave the values directly for testing
        password: 'admin123',
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: 'admin-cli',
      }),
      {
        headers: { 
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      }
      ).then(function(response) {       
        console.log(response.data);     
    }); 
    
  }


  async newKeyToken(data: any){
    const newdata = await this.keycloaktokennew(data);
    if (newdata=="undefined") {
      throw new BadRequestException(INVALID_CREDENTIALS);
    }
    else{
    console.log("-------------------this is Result needed var-----------------");
    console.log(newdata);
    console.log("-------------------this is Result needed var-----------------");
    return newdata;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you aren't returning anything from the first functions `.then` you may want to `return response.data`

Comment: `.then(function(response) { console.log(response.data); }` will ensure that you return `undefined` - also `"undefined"` is not `undefined`

Comment: by the way, remove `async` from`keycloaktokennew` and just `return this.httpService.axiosRef.post` - no need to async/await a function that just returns something that returns a Promise .... also, never mix `async`/`await` with `.then`/`.catch` - unless there's a VERY good reason

Comment: @JaromandaX I think it's a bad idea to encourage implicit functionality rather than explicitly declaring that functionality. Just because you don't *have to declare the function async*  it's good practise to make everything that's returning a Promise async to let IDE's and the programmer know that things need to be awaited or consumed.

Comment: Thank you so much @Dale , i was confused with the first return in first function and assuming it is returning the value. Thank you so much

Comment: @JaromandaX That said... One should never mix async/await with .then unless (as you said) there's a very good reason.

Comment: @Joel `async function fn() { return await returnsPromise(); }` is NEVER good code - I may excuse `async function fn() { return returnsPromise(); }` - but I still don't like it

Comment: @Joel I agree that's wrong, so, in that case `function fn() { return returnsPromise(); }` is the **only** correct code - never `async function fn() { return await returnsPromise(); }` - unless you want your cake and eat it too

Comment: @Joel assuming there's lots of (ONLY synchronous only) code above the `return await ...`  you think that actually makes more sense than not making the function `async` in the first place? I do disagree, and can't see anywhere on MDN that suggests any function that returns a Promise should be made `async`

Comment: well ... look at the code in the question, no assumptions needed, and why the hell can't assumptions be relevant to the code pattern @Joel

Comment: @JaromandaX exactly, there's no synchronous functions declared anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (newdata=="undefined")` should be `(!newdata)`, as in current flow it expect incoming `"undefined"` from previous function which is `undefined` because you do not return any information from callback.

```
    ).then(function(response) {       
        console.log(response.data);     
    });
```

Additionally you should return data from your promise.

```
    ).then(function(response) {       
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the response

```
then(function(response) {       
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;     
    });
```

61

The console will print the result of evaluating an expression. The result of evaluating console.log() is undefined since console.log does not explicitly return something. It has the side effect of printing to the console.